# When the query result is "null" it throws an error

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

I have a problem with my app. Everytime that i got a query that returns 0 elements. If the query return  data everything works ok.

So, i have a class and one of the members its another class.

```
result.Conteudo = (from c in db.ConteudoCaixa
                      select new ConteudoVM
                        {
                          ID = c.id,
                          Processo = c.Processo,
                         }
                       )
                       .Where(i=>i.NumeroCaixa == id)   //this id comes from a FORM
                       .ToList();
```

If this query return 0 elements, i got the error

System.NullReferenceException: 'A referência de objecto não foi definida como uma instância de um objecto.'

I cant see whats wrong...

Thanks

EDIT:

This is table db.ConteudoCaixa

[image]

and my class ConteudoVM

```
public  class ConteudoVM
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Processo { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public int NumeroCaixa{ get; set; }
        public string Posicao { get; set; }

    }
```

EDIT 2

This is my error when i try do use an ID that doesnt exist

[image]

Comment: .Where(i=>  (i == null)? false : i.NumeroCaixa == id)

Comment: Hi. Tanks, but it gives same error

Comment: I suggest converting your code to use method chaining, and to use intermediate variables. That will help you narrow down where the NRE is occurring. Debugging a null reference exception when your breakpoint spans 10+ lines is problematic!

Comment: ive found it. the problem was not with result.Conteudo but with result that was null. Many tanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is because if the Where clause is not matched the result is null .. not null in your database.

.First() or .FirstOrDefault() must be added befor you convert ToList() so the result is can be returned as null = default ... then you can check for any items returned befoir trying to use the data.

do this....
var result = (from c in db.ConteudoCaixa
select new ConteudoVM
{
ID = c.id,
Processo = c.Processo,
}
)
.Where(i=>i.NumeroCaixa == id)   //this id comes from a FORM
.FirstOrDefault()
.ToList();

if(result != null)
result.Conteudo = result;

Comment: hi. this doenst make sense. with .FirstOrDefault() you will get only one record, and not all records. the .ToList() after .FirstOrDefault() will do nothing

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself, what is the input in your Where? What does every `i` in the Where stand for?

Have you tried:

```
var items = (from c in db.ConteudoCaixa
                  select new ConteudoVM
                    {
                      ID = c.id,
                      Processo = c.Processo,
                     }
                   )
                   .Take(3)
                   .ToList();
```

So without the Where, taking only a few elements to prevent fetching your million `ConteudoCaixas` (whatever that may be).

What is items? It is a List of three `ConteudoVMs`, where every ConteudoVM has two filled properties: Id and Processo. All other properties of each of the three ConteudoVMs have their default values, among which property `NumeroCaixa`.

Solution: do the Where before Select!

> When using LINQ always try to limit the number of items that you process. This means, put your Where as soon as possible.

Apart from that it is more efficient to process fewer elements, it also allows you to use properties in your Where that you don't use later on.

Apart from that, it is seldom a good idea to mix LINQ query syntax with method syntax. It deteriorates readability.

```
int id = ...
var result = dbContext.ConteudoCaixas
    .Where(contuedoCaixa => contuedoCaixa.NumeroCaixa  == id)
    .Select(contuedoCaixa => new ContuedoVM
    {
        ID = contuedoCaixa .id,
        Processo = contuedoCaixa .Processo,
    })
    .ToList();
```

In words: from the collection of ContuedoCaixas, keep only thos contuedoCaixas that have a value for property NumeroCaixa that equals id. From every remaining contuedoCaixa make one new ContuedoVM with only the properties ID and Processo filled. Finally put the created ContuedoVMs in a List.

It could be that you want that every created ContuedoVM also has property NumeroCaixa filled, consider to add it to your Select. This is probably useless, because you know that it will have a value equal to id.

Comment: Hi, after all the problem wasnt with my query, but with the var result that was null. this query was putting the results in result.Conteudo, but result was null...

Answer (score 0):

You only select
ID and Processco
But you trying to access NumeroCaixa so NumeroCaixa be default value ( in case of int is 0)

If your compare id is not zero so the result of list is always return empty or null